# Display not appearing in Color Management / Devices under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, color-profiles

I never had any problem setting up an ICM profile for my monitor, but now I cannot see any display device under Windows 7 / Control Panel / Color Management / Devices. All I can see are printers, but not my display listed. I only have one monitor and I have the latest nVidia drivers.

[image: problem]

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? If you can guide me to any Microsoft forum where there are experts in this field, it would help too.

Comment: Is your monitor shown under "Devices" in `Start-->Devices and Printers`?

Comment: Yes, it is visible there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution was to reinstall Windows.